# Add or remove element(s) to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an existing array of objects :

```
existingArray = [
   {object1: 'object1'},
   {object2: 'object2'}
   {object3: 'object3'},
]
```

I receive a new one :

```
newArray = [
   {object2: 'object2'},
   {object3: 'object3'},
   {object4: 'object4'}
]
```

I want only to modify the existing one to get the new one as the result (push+splice)

Here is what I have for now (is there a better way ?)

```
 for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    // loop first to push new elements
    var responseToTxt = JSON.stringify(newArray[i]);

    var newStatement = false;
    for(var j = 0; j < existingArray.length; j++){
        var statementToTxt = JSON.stringify(existingArray[j]);

        if(statementToTxt === responseToTxt && !newStatement){
            newStatement = true;
        }           
    }

    if(!newStatement){
        statements.push(response[i]);
    }  
}

var statementsToSplice = [];

for (var i = 0; i < existingArray.length; i++) {
    // then loop a second time to split elements not anymore on the new array
    var statementToTxt = JSON.stringify(existingArray[i]);        
    var elementPresent = false;
    var element = false;

    for(var j = 0; j < newArray.length; j++){       
        var responseToTxt = JSON.stringify(newArray[j]);
        if(responseToTxt === statementToTxt && !elementPresent){
            elementPresent = true;
        } else {
            element = i;   
        }
    }

    if(!elementPresent){   
        statementsToSplice.push(element);
    }  
}
```

Then I needed to split multiple times in the array :

```
existingArray = statementsToSplice.reduceRight(function (arr, it) {
        arr.splice(it, 1);
        return arr;
    }, existingArray.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a }));
```

Here is the example :

https://jsfiddle.net/docmz22b/

So the final output should always be the new array, but only by push or splice the old one.

In this case, the final outpout will be

```
existingArray = [
       {object2: 'object2'},
       {object3: 'object3'}
       {object4: 'object4'},
    ]
```

The new array could contains multiple new elements and/or deleted elements that is currently in the existingArray

Comment: I don't think you're explaining this clearly.  If you want the new one as the result, then why is there anything more than a simple assignment required?  E.g., `existingArray = newArray`

Comment: why are the properties wrapped in an array?

Comment: Because I'm using it in an angular where I don't want to make existingArray = newArray, because then All animations are refreshing if I do that replacement. If I only push or splice, then only the new/old elements will animate

Comment: please supply a sample of the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shift()` and `push()`

```
existingArray.shift(); //Removes the first element of the array
existingArray.push({'object4' : 'object4'});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/4ox2xuge/)

Comment: But the 2 arrays are dynamics. I mean, I don't know how many new items needs to be added or removed

Comment: You can still use the push method. Just push the new array (with new elements) into the existing array.

As for shift, put it through a loop if you know how many are going to be removed.

Comment: Why does it matter that you don't know the number of new items? Just run the code for each new item

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps. It features `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.some`.

1. Splice unwanted items
2. Look if object with same property exist

   - If yes, then assign new object
   - Else push the object

```js
var existingArray = [
        { object1: 'object1' },
        { object2: 'object2' },
        { object3: 'object3' },
    ],
    newArray = [
        { object2: 'object22' },
        { object3: 'object33' },
        { object4: 'object44' }
    ];

function update(base, change) {
    var changeKeys = change.map(function (a) { return Object.keys(a)[0]; }),
        i = 0;
    while (i < base.length) {
        if (!~changeKeys.indexOf(Object.keys(base[i])[0])) {
            base.splice(i, 1);
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    change.forEach(function (a) {
        var aKey = Object.keys(a)[0];
        !base.some(function (b, i, bb) {
            if (aKey === Object.keys(b)[0]) {
                bb[i] = a; // if that does not work, use bb.splice(i, 1, a);
                return true;
            }
        }) && base.push(a);
    });
}

update(existingArray, newArray);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(existingArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost 100% sure that there is a better way to do it, but at least this works, feel free to comment any suggestions / optimizations.

```
existingArray = [
   {object1: 'object1'},
   {object2: 'object2'},
   {object3: 'object3'}
];

newArray = [
   {object2: 'object2'},
   {object3: 'object3'},
   {object4: 'object4'}
];

// Loop all the old values, if is not in the new array, remove it
existingArray.forEach(function(item) {
  if(!inArray(item, newArray)) {
    var idx = indexOfObjectInArray(item, existingArray);
    existingArray.splice(idx, 1);
  }
});

// Loop all the new values, if  is not in the new array, push it
newArray.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!inArray(item, existingArray)) {
    existingArray.push(item);
  }
});

// Auxiliar functions
function inArray(initialValue, array) {
  testValue = JSON.stringify(initialValue);

  return array.some(function(item) {
    return testValue == JSON.stringify(item);
  });
}

function indexOfObjectInArray(initialValue, array) {
  var result = -1;
  testValue = JSON.stringify(initialValue);

  array.forEach(function(item, idx) {
    if (testValue == JSON.stringify(item)) {
      result = idx;
    };
  });

  return result;
}
```